# Changing how the directory name is displayed in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, prompt

When I change directories in the Ubuntu terminal the full path of the directory is displayed. How can I change it so that only the current directory I am working in is displayed?

**username@computer:directory$** is what I want it to look like. I found elsewhere that I should edit the variable PS1 in the .bashrc file, but I have no idea to what.

Comment: Whats the output of `echo "$PS1"` ?

Comment: \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

Comment: Comments are not chat. If someone asks for clarification, then edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `\w` to `\W` in your `$PS1`.

So, your `~/.bashrc` should contain something like:

```
PS1='[\e]0;\u@\h: \W\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$'
```

See `man bash`, section `PROMPTING`, for list of all escape sequences supported by bash and their meaning.

Comment: If this answer works for you, then click the tick `✓`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last `\w` to `\W` of `PS1` environment variable.

From `man bash` :

> \w  :   the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a
>   tilde (uses  the  value  of  the  PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
>
> \W   :  the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde

So you need :

```
PS1='[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$ '
```

In `~/.bashrc`, there is this snippet :

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

you can basically change the `\w`s to `\W`s or you can selectively change matching your needs. otherwise you can put your desired `PS1` value at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file to override them all. As upon starting of a login shell `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` it will be available in all login and non-login interactive sessions.

If you want to make it applicable to all users you should look at `/etc/bash.bashrc` and remove the relevant `PS1` snippets from individual `~/.bashrc` files.